# AWS serverless url not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I published an AWS Lambda NET solution that responded with an AWS Serverless URL:

```
https://je7p92w69l.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod
```

When I got to this link it is 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the root path for your API: your API's URL is https://je7p92w69l.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod which seems to be correct. However, haven't you mapped any API? Let's say you are creating a /books API, then you should invoke your API like https://je7p92w69l.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/books

If you're getting 404 it just means that API Gateway is responding properly but this URI on your API does not exist. Just figure out the path you created and it will work.

On the left-hand side of your API you should see your resources, and, inside it, your URIs.

[image]